# "raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None" error on Glassdoor review scraper from Page2API

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

```
import requests
import json

api_url = 'https://www.page2api.com/api/v1/scrape'
payload = {
    "api_key": "b9163469e0dc62bbe6e06d1bc888cd55ef0c3474",
    "premium_proxy": "us",
    "batch": {
        "urls": "https://www.glassdoor.com/Reviews/Apple-Reviews-E1138_P[451,480,1].htm",
        #https://www.glassdoor.com/Reviews/Apple-Reviews-E1138_P[1,5,1].htm
        "concurrency": 1,
        "merge_results": True
    },
    "parse": {
        "reviews": [
            {
                "_parent": "div.gdReview",
                "author_info": ".authorInfo >> text",
                "rating": "span.ratingNumber >> text",
            }
        ]
    }
}

headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'text/plain'}
response = requests.post(api_url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
result = json.loads(response.text)
```

print(result)

I'm using a code from Page2API that functions as a Glassdoor review scrapper. This code results in the error "raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None" from time to time. I don't know what causes this error let alone how to fix it. If anyone could give a solution to this problem, I would be very grateful.

Comment: It means the thing you tried to parse as JSON was `None` which isn't valid JSON. If you need more help than that, please [edit] to show your troubleshooting efforts.

Comment: Also, if that's your personal API key, probably have the provider kill it and create a new one.